# How can I publish the layer in geoserver using swagger api?

Tags: swagger, geoserver

I am building the geoserver api application to handle all the geoserver data using api, as I was able to create workspace and data store but I was unable to publish the layers using the api,
here I was using geoserver swagger api here I was unable to found the api to publish the layer.

I used Geoserver swagger api in python flask application as backend api, I was able to publish the workspace and data store but i was unable to publish the layer from the data store

Comment: without seeing the requests you have made and their payloads it's impossible to answer this question